# Racing wheel pulls to the right / How to fix?

Tags: dirt-3

I have purchased the newest Dirt3 Complete Edition.

Everything works fine, with one exception: 
My Logitech G27 Racing wheel always pulls to the right. I can't find any solution, even if this racing wheel is on the [supported devices](http://support.feralinteractive.com/en/mac-games/dirt3/faqs/wheels/) list.

If I play the same device in other games (various Need for Speed versions) it works fine, so I assume it is connected as it should.

Do you know how I can fix - or at least reduce - this 'pull to the right' force feedback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a known problem - a lots of gamers with racing wheels report it. We have to wait until Codemasters fix this bug.

See: https://steamcommunity.com/app/321040/discussions/1/611702631209592196/?insideModal=1